# Linux Mint 17.3 wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint, wifi-driver

As title says my wifi connection keeps dropping, sometimes after 10 minutes, sometimes after a few hours after connecting.

I have searched for the solution and looks like it's the common problem on linux machines.

I've done all updates, but I'm not sure what to think about my driver version, and what else to try.

Here is information about my computer:

```
Computer: HP Elitebook 840
OS: Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
Cinnamon version: 2.8.6
Kernel: 3.19.0-generic
```

When I run `lshw -c network` command:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 64:51:06:9e:b0:62
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.3-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:50 memory:d0700000-d071ffff memory:d073e000-d073efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 18:cf:5e:81:b5:fd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.131 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:19 memory:d0500000-d0503fff
```

I don't know what else to say. Hopefully you can help me to find the solution.

**Edit:**

Here is information about my wifi connection:

```
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
    Group Cipher : CCMP
    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

And output for `tail -f /var/log/dmesg`:

```
[    7.142644] init: failsafe main process (762) killed by TERM signal
[    7.281183] init: samba-ad-dc main process (894) terminated with status 1
[    7.862247] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    7.870277] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    7.965046] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP HD Webcam (05c8:0369)
[    7.973955] input: HP HD Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input25
[    7.974072] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    7.974076] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    8.140923] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    8.172888] input: ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer as /devices/platform/lis3lv02d/input/input26
```

**Edit2:**

Output for `lspci -vnn | grep -i net`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM [8086:155a] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
```

Comment: Have you used Driver Manager to install the current proprietary drivers?

Comment: @acejavelin Driver Manager says that 1 proprietary driver in use. https://i.imgur.com/7izXmNC.png

Comment: Have you tried the b43 installer? Recommended doesn't always mean "best", in Mint it tends to more mean "safest" although often not optimal

Comment: @acejavelin Looks like it didn't help, I tried firmware-b43-installer. Should I try firmware-b43legacy-installer as well?

Comment: It can't hurt, you can always roll back. What network are you connecting to? Not specifically which one, but what frequency (2.4Ghz or 5Ghz), encryption, etc.

Comment: I would also look at the dmesg output to see what is causing it to disconnect using `tail -f /var/log/dmesg`... if it's connecting then the drivers are probably working

Comment: @acejavelin I updated my post with the information you asked for.

Comment: thanks... That's a dmesg of when it fails and drops? I don't see any net or wlan activity at all...

Comment: @acejavelin i ran it after a drop happened, shows nothing else.

Comment: Can you please post the out put of `lspci -vnn | grep -i net`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae added the output into the post

Comment: Have you tried following in detail this answer? It contains the standard recipe for removing the buggy `wl` driver, and for substituting it with the FOSS driver `b43`. I understand you tried that already, but can you confirm you followed **all** of the steps here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/38700#38700

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I followed those steps a few days ago. I haven't noticed a single drop for now. I would like to say that the problem is solved, but I'll wait more before being 100% sure.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I will accept it in a week if there are no problems through a week. It's just to be sure that problem is gone.

Comment: @kabanen After the bounty expires? Gee, that's too bad.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm sorry, I didn't know that there are a bounty expiration time. I will accept your answer after 2 days if no problems meanwhile.

Comment: Have you tried looking into energy/power saving options? I had similar issues with laptop not being able to connect to some APs when running on battery power. Disabling power saving for wlan solved the issue

Comment: I'm happy to see it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the answer lies in following **in detail** (I'll explain in a second) the instructions [in this Askubuntu reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/38700#38700). Let me remark that:

1. The proprietary driver, `wl` is of considerably lower quality than the OpenSource one, [b43](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/). There are many reasons for this, but, blurb notwithstanding, **your** case is a perfect proof of this. Just remember though that the FOSS driver `b43` still misses some features, the most noteworthy of which is an ability to operate at `5GHz`. The list of currently missing features can be found at the second link above.
2. `b43` and `wl` support, to a large extent, the same devices (not exactly, but close). To prevent possible mistakes, the installation of `wl` *blacklists* `b43`. This is what, on the first reference above, modifying the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` is all about. So, removing the package `bcmwl-kernel-source` is not, by itself, enough to allow `b43` to work, one also needs to make sure that the module `b43` is not blacklisted. This is, most likely, the reason why you failed to make `b43` work the first time around, and the reason why I suggested you follow the instructions above closely.
3. Though the driver `b43` is OpenSource, a component in it (the so-called *firmware*) is proprietary; for this reason the purest among all Linux distributions (Debian, Arch,...) do not provide the driver and its accompanying firmware out of the box (nor the proprietary driver, either). Yet both drivers and the firmware can be downloaded in all distros. For what little experience I have, this is **the** major stumbling block for people who just moved to Linux from Windows or MacOS.

Should you run into other problems in the future, make sure you check the list of currently unavailable features (second reference above), it might spare you running into a wall.